# How can i just retry if if I get this specific error?

Tags: python, error-handling, request

if my scripts runs long enough I get this specific error:

***KeyError: 'data'**
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
...line 61, in

... line 49 in programm

```
zeit = get_nanopool_time_to_next_epoch()
```

...line 33,
in get_nanopool_time_to_next_epochwebseite['data']

I need to get this ["data"]. How can i implement that if the request fails, it should just try again and again till if its working.
Apreciate your help!

```
import requests
import time
import os

def get_nanopool_time_to_next_epoch():
    while True:

        url=f"https://api.nanopool.org/v1/eth/network/timetonextepoch"
        resp = requests.get(url)
        webseite = requests.get(url).json()
        while resp.status_code >= 300:
            try:
                webseite['data']
                print("--------------------------------------------")
                print("Http Fehler", resp.status_code)
                #print(resp.content)
            except:
                time.sleep(30)
                webseite['data']
                print("--------------------------------------------")
                print("Http Fehler", resp.status_code)
                #print(resp.content)
        #webseite = requests.get(url).json()
        while 'data' not in webseite:
            try:
                time.sleep(50)
                webseite['data']
            except:
                
                #continue
                while 'data' not in webseite:
                    time.sleep(30)
                    webseite['data']
                    if ["data"]==[]:
                        time.sleep(30)
                print("--------------------------------------------")
                print("'data' nicht im Dictionary")
            return webseite['data']
        else:
            return webseite['data']
#time.sleep(30)

def programm():
    while True:
        zeit = get_nanopool_time_to_next_epoch()
        puffer=int(420)

        while zeit > puffer:
            zeit = get_nanopool_time_to_next_epoch()
            puffer=int (420)
            print("Zeit zum DAG-Wechsel in Sekunden:",zeit)
            time.sleep(30) #Refresh Zeit
            while zeit < puffer:
                print("Neustart in",int(zeit)) # Zeit zur nächsten DAG Epoche in Sekunden
                os.startfile("C:/Users/Simon/Desktop/Minerrrestart1.bat")
                print("restart")
                time.sleep(10000)
                break
        break
while True:
    programm()
    break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `try` and `except` statements and a `while True` loop.:

```
while True:
    try:
        zeit = get_nanopool_time_to_next_epoch()
    except KeyError:
        continue
    break
```

Here, `zeit = get_nanopool_time_to_next_epoch()` will keep on being run until it doesn't result in a `KeyError`.

You can also add delays using `time.sleep()` if you want to wait a period of time before trying to run the command again.

The full function would be:

```
def programm():
    while True:
        while True:
            try:
                zeit = get_nanopool_time_to_next_epoch()
            except KeyError:
                continue
            break
        puffer=int(420)

        while zeit > puffer:
            while True:
                try:
                    zeit = get_nanopool_time_to_next_epoch()
                except KeyError:
                    continue
            break

            puffer=int (420)
            print("Zeit zum DAG-Wechsel in Sekunden:",zeit)
            time.sleep(30) #Refresh Zeit
            while zeit < puffer:
                print("Neustart in",int(zeit)) # Zeit zur nächsten DAG Epoche in Sekunden
                os.startfile("C:/Users/Simon/Desktop/Minerrrestart1.bat")
                print("restart")
                time.sleep(10000)
                break
        break
```

Comment: Where exactly can i paste this? Is my extra error handling then unnecessary?

Comment: @wqeeekendwrrar Replace line 49 with the above. What extra error handling?

Comment: So i paste this directly after the program() function?

Comment: @wqeeekendwrrar Yes, after `While True`.

Comment: Im checking it out, the error sometimes comes after 5 mins and sometimes after 3 hours. The break statement does not let me go for the following script now.

Comment: @wqeeekendwrrar You can also change the same command after `while zeit > puffer:` in case the error occurs there as well.

Comment: Can you send the whole script into this like you thought? Im running on some problems now, and im not sure if copied the code into the right place

Comment: @wqeeekendwrrar I have edited in the whole function, just replace the `programm` function with that.

Comment: Yes ok here we go now. Thank you i will give you an update!

Answer (score 0):

If you are specific to requests library, like you want to keep attempting until it gives you **200**, following approaches could work.

- Set max retries for your code

```
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

conn = requests.Session()
conn.mount(URL, HTTPAdapter(max_retries=max_retries))
```

or you can just implement this for infinite attempts as:

```
while (resp.status_code!=200):
    url=f"https://api.nanopool.org/v1/eth/network/timetonextepoch"
    resp = requests.get(url)
    webseite = requests.get(url).json()
    #blah blah
```

or you can just use [urllib3](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) along with its [retry](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html#urllib3.util.retry.Retry) utility for more robustness.